# Server upgrading from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, expressionengine

My hosting server is upgrading from PHP version 5.2.x to 5.3.x and I have some WordPress and ExpressionEngine installs. I am wondering if anyone knows if this upgrade will effect my site in any way.

I know that the minimum requirements for EE is 5.1.6 and for WordPress it's 5.2.4. So, it seems like they should be ok, but I have never had this happen and just want to be aware of what to look out for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Is there a Wordpress version that is incompatible with PHP 5.3?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/28603/178)

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade is not before time -- php5.2 has been officially out of support for nearly two years already. (Some would even say that a service provider that is still on 5.2 is being actively negligent of their security)

Wordpress is a popular package, used on a lot of sites. Many of them will have been running 5.3 for years. Even if Wordpress didn't work on 5.3 once upon a time, it would have been forced to update to support it a long time ago.

I remember three years ago Drupal was taking a lot of flak because Drupal 6 wasn't fully compatible with 5.3 and they hadn't finished Drupal 7 yet. That was *three years* ago.

In short, as long as you're on a recent version of Wordpress (or indeed any other CMS), and you're using plugins that are properly supported and up to date, there's no reason at all to worry.

Conversely, if you're on a version that is old enough not to support php 5.3, then you need to upgrade urgently, because the stuff that was taken out of PHP between 5.2 and 5.3 was all done for security considerations; they removed and deprecated old PHP features that were fundamentally insecure. Therefore, it follows that if your software doesn't work with in 5.3, it means it's likely using those insecure features.

Final thought: http://wordpress.org/about/stats/

I note that the WP stats page shows that a third of WP installations are on 5.3. That should be sufficient proof that it works.

(I'm a little worried about the two thirds who are still on 5.2, though, given what I said in the first paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when doing upgrades like that, a grid service provider will manage that transition, and if you have any issues with your sites not working, you can get help from them.

However, I think you're not likely to see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

What version are your EE sites on? If you're on the 1.x branch, then you'll want to upgrade to at least 1.7.0.